# What is the paper at Saki's desk in From the New World about?

Tags: japanese-language, from-the-new-world

I've been wondering this for ages:

At the end of *From the New World*, Saki has this piece of paper on her desk. Below you can see it (and somebody translated them to Spanish).

Apparently these are names, and some of them are followed by a number. Unfortunately I don't recognise any of those names so I'm not sure what is this paper about.

At first I guessed it was some sort of deceased people list (numbers representing their age?). However the fourth name reads "New Yuubari", so it sounds like a *place* rather than somebody... but it lacks a number, so it could actually be a *headline*, as in "the following people died at New Yuubari" - same thing for "Shinamoto", which makes sense - but then the first three names lack a headline.

So I'm not sure - *what* is this paper?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are all place names. 町 is a marker for a town/block/neighborhood/district or road/street.

夕張 can be pronounced "yuubari." The translators were probably trying to simply the names as if they were actual place names. E.g. "New Amsterdam."

The story is primarily set is 神栖66町 (Kamisu 66th District), there are 8 other districts:

- 「夕張新生町」（北海道）, Yuubari New District (Hokkaidou region)
- 「白石71町」（東北）, Shiroishi 71th District (Touhoku region)
- 「胎内84町」（北陸）, Tainai 84th District (Hokuriku region)
- 「小海95町」（中部）, Koumi 95th District (Chuubu region)
- 「精華59町」（関西）, Seika 59th District (Kansai region)
- 「石見銀山町」（中国）, Iwami Ginzan (Silver Mine) District ([Chuugoku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%ABgoku_region) region)
- 「四万十町」（四国）, Shimanto District (Shikoku region)
- 「西海77町」（九州）, Saikai 77th District (Kyushu region)

These are all named after real life locations, including [Kamisu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamisu,_Ibaraki).

Comment: Nice! Do we know what was the purpose of the paper?

Comment: They're other settlements in Japan (there's 9 of them total), so I assume she's writing stuff about Goma, Akki, etc. to share with other the other settlements.