# What are the real world locations for the Districts mentioned in From the New World?

Tags: from-the-new-world, tourism

Given that in the series, Tokyo is visited, I assumed that the districts mentioned have real world locations.

According to the [Wikia Page](http://shinsekaiyori.wikia.com/wiki/Kamisu_66),

> Although Kamisu 66 is the only district that appears in the actual story, there are other district names known, such as Shiroishi 71 in a location called Tohoku, Tainai 84 in Hokuriku, and Koumi 95 in Chuubu.

so I tried plotting them on a [Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zZtRgpmVI-xE.ktMcCUs3vuUc&usp=sharing) ([static image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz4ow.jpg)), but when I tried and search for Tohoku, Hokuriku and Chuubu I didn't get a single place/prefecture to be confident that it is the district, and Shiroishi 71 to me seems a bit too close to Tokyo.

So I am wondering: what are the real world locations of the districts?

NOTE: I won't be allowing people to edit the map I have linked to as I have and plan to add other points which only are useful to myself. You can use [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/) to plot out the locations for your answer if it helps.

Comment: See [this answer](http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9246/63) for additional details. You also need to grant permission to the map.