# Does the Ethics Committee control all of Japan?

Tags: from-the-new-world

According to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/9246/1587) it appears that each of the districts are in each of [Japan's Regions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regions_of_Japan)

Tomiko, who lives in Kamisu 66 is the head of the Ethics Committee and she wanted Saki, who also lived in Kamisu 66, to take her place one day.

I am wondering if the Ethics Committee's Tomiko is the head of control of all of Japan, or if each region/district has their own Ethics Committee. If the latter, do they all share the same ruleset (particularly regarding the age a child can be terminated being changed to 17 years)?

Answer (score 1):

In the novel, each regions doesn't have communication channel each other.
([Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%B0%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%82%88%E3%82%8A_(%E5%B0%8F%E8%AA%AC)) describe it too.)
There are no way to control all regions from one ethics committee.

I think the fundamental rules such as got human rights at 17 years old is same, because it's created by scientist group.